# List all the paths which contains an attribute

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have following JSON, in which I want to list all parent node paths where `path` attribute is present.

```
{
        "ServiceId": {
            "type": "string",
            "admin": "false"
        },
        "NormalizedEvents": {
            "type": "list",
            "path": "/data/../../nEvents"
        },
        "Events": {
            "type" : "list",
            "path": "/data/../../Events"
        }
    }
```

In this case, I need output like, `$.NormalizedEvents` and `$.Events`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JSONPath options to output [path instead of value](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-vs-value).

JSONPath

```
$.[*][?(@.path)]
```

Output

```
[
   "$['NormalizedEvents']",
   "$['Events']"
]
```

> JsonPath expressions can use the dot–notation
> `$.NormalizedEvents`
>
> or
> the bracket–notation
> `$['NormalizedEvents']`

Online Tool : [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)
[image]